# Icon definitions in SCSS file

Tags: css, sass, icons

Below is the picture of what I'm seeing in `scss` file that define icons in our web app.

[image]

They must be pointing to some fonts we had purchased but the individual who handled this at the time did not map all the icons.

I'm trying to figure out how they're actually mapped. Are the hexadecimal looking numbers the coordinates of those icons in the file that contains them -- kind of like sprite images?

If so, how do I get those coordinates? Also, in the sample image I included, what file are they pointing to? I see a reference to a font-path at the top but not sure how to interpret it.

Below is the image showing what's in the `fonts` folder:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you determined them as a font?

Comment: I’m not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: Your files seems like font icons. First, you should identify them with @font-face tag. Example link: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-ever-thought-about-using-font-face-for-icons--net-11233

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at the article and post here any questions I may have after that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) for generating font icons. Its really cool service and easy to use.

Also this was the refference I shared before: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-ever-thought-about-using-font-face-for-icons--net-11233

Looks like you can close the topic?